# How to prevent opening a new tab during scraping with puppeteer, when clicking a button with ng-click directive?

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, puppeteer, target

When scraping a website containing a button that navigates to a pdf file when clicked, I would normally remove target="_blank" attribute to prevent from opening in a new tab. 
However, this time around, clicking the button triggers some function like this: `ng-click="$ctrl.openPriceList()"`, pdf gets open in a new tab and removing target attribute on button element does nothing. 
How to prevent opening in a new tab in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `window.open`:

```js
((window, open) => {
    window.open = (url) => {
        open.call(window, url, '_self');
    };
})(window, window.open);
```

Comment: @Arson glad I could help! please select it as the correct answer since many ppl don't read comments.